# Bootstrap Carousel Template not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am trying to get the [Carousel Template](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/#) to work. I downloaded bootstrap, changed all the necessary paths in the `index.html` file after copying it over. However, when I open `index.html` locally, it still looks different from how it is supposed to be. I looked online and seems like other people have experienced the same problem and the problem seems to be that `jQuery` wasn't working and that `#myCarousel` needed to be call upon, which I also tried doing with my little script at the end of my head.

I can't figure out what is wrong... Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
        <link href="css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

        <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
        <link href="carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script>
        $(function(){
            $('#myCarousel').carousel();
        });
        </script>
    </head>
<!-- NAVBAR
================================================== -->
    <body>
        <div class="navbar-wrapper">
            <div class="container">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            </button>
                            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
                        </div>
                        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                                <li class="dropdown">
                                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                        <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>

            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Carousel
        ================================================== -->
        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <!-- Indicators -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                <div class="item active">
                    <img class="first-slide" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="First slide">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h1>Example headline.</h1>
                            <p>Note: If you're viewing this page via a <code>file://</code> URL, the "next" and "previous" Glyphicon buttons on the left and right might not load/display properly due to web browser security rules.</p>
                            <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Sign up today</a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img class="second-slide" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Second slide">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h1>Another example headline.</h1>
                            <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                            <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img class="third-slide" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Third slide">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
                            <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                            <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Browse gallery</a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div><!-- /.carousel -->


        <!-- Marketing messaging and featurettes
        ================================================== -->
        <!-- Wrap the rest of the page in another container to center all the content. -->

        <div class="container marketing">

            <!-- Three columns of text below the carousel -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <img class="img-circle" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="140" height="140">
                    <h2>Heading</h2>
                    <p>Donec sed odio dui. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Praesent commodo cursus magna.</p>
                    <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
                </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <img class="img-circle" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="140" height="140">
                    <h2>Heading</h2>
                    <p>Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh.</p>
                    <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
                </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <img class="img-circle" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="140" height="140">
                    <h2>Heading</h2>
                    <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
                    <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
                </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
            </div><!-- /.row -->


            <!-- START THE FEATURETTES -->

            <hr class="featurette-divider">

            <div class="row featurette">
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <h2 class="featurette-heading">First featurette heading. <span class="text-muted">It'll blow your mind.</span></h2>
                    <p class="lead">Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <img class="featurette-image img-responsive center-block" data-src="holder.js/500x500/auto" alt="Generic placeholder image">
                </div>
            </div>

            <hr class="featurette-divider">

            <div class="row featurette">
                <div class="col-md-7 col-md-push-5">
                    <h2 class="featurette-heading">Oh yeah, it's that good. <span class="text-muted">See for yourself.</span></h2>
                    <p class="lead">Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5 col-md-pull-7">
                    <img class="featurette-image img-responsive center-block" data-src="holder.js/500x500/auto" alt="Generic placeholder image">
                </div>
            </div>

            <hr class="featurette-divider">

            <div class="row featurette">
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <h2 class="featurette-heading">And lastly, this one. <span class="text-muted">Checkmate.</span></h2>
                    <p class="lead">Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <img class="featurette-image img-responsive center-block" data-src="holder.js/500x500/auto" alt="Generic placeholder image">
                </div>
            </div>

            <hr class="featurette-divider">

            <!-- /END THE FEATURETTES -->


            <!-- FOOTER -->
            <footer>
                <p class="pull-right"><a href="#">Back to top</a></p>
                <p>&copy; 2015 Company, Inc. &middot; <a href="#">Privacy</a> &middot; <a href="#">Terms</a></p>
            </footer>

        </div><!-- /.container -->


        <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
        ================================================== -->
        <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
        <script src="js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: we would be able to help you better if you can create a fiddle to replicate your problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo have not placed the links to the scripts (`bootstrap.min.js`) and CSS (`bootstrap.min.css` & `carousel.css`) correctly. Please find below code snippet for Bootstrap Carousel:

```js
$(function(){
            $('#myCarousel').carousel();
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


        <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
        <!-- Link to bootstrap.min.css-->
        <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        
        <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
        <!-- Link to carousel.css -->
        <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- NAVBAR
================================================== -->
    <body>
        <div class="navbar-wrapper">
            <div class="container">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            </button>
                            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
                        </div>
                        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                                <li class="dropdown">
                                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                        <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>

            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Carousel
        ================================================== -->
        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <!-- Indicators -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                <div class="item active">
                    <img class="first-slide" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="First slide">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h1>Example headline.</h1>
                            <p>Note: If you're viewing this page via a <code>file://</code> URL, the "next" and "previous" Glyphicon buttons on the left and right might not load/display properly due to web browser security rules.</p>
                            <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Sign up today</a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img class="second-slide" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Second slide">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h1>Another example headline.</h1>
                            <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                            <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img class="third-slide" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Third slide">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
                            <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                            <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Browse gallery</a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div><!-- /.carousel -->


        <!-- Marketing messaging and featurettes
        ================================================== -->
        <!-- Wrap the rest of the page in another container to center all the content. -->

        <div class="container marketing">

            <!-- Three columns of text below the carousel -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <img class="img-circle" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="140" height="140">
                    <h2>Heading</h2>
                    <p>Donec sed odio dui. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Praesent commodo cursus magna.</p>
                    <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
                </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <img class="img-circle" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="140" height="140">
                    <h2>Heading</h2>
                    <p>Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh.</p>
                    <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
                </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <img class="img-circle" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="140" height="140">
                    <h2>Heading</h2>
                    <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
                    <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
                </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
            </div><!-- /.row -->


            <!-- START THE FEATURETTES -->

            <hr class="featurette-divider">

            <div class="row featurette">
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <h2 class="featurette-heading">First featurette heading. <span class="text-muted">It'll blow your mind.</span></h2>
                    <p class="lead">Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <img class="featurette-image img-responsive center-block" data-src="holder.js/500x500/auto" alt="Generic placeholder image">
                </div>
            </div>

            <hr class="featurette-divider">

            <div class="row featurette">
                <div class="col-md-7 col-md-push-5">
                    <h2 class="featurette-heading">Oh yeah, it's that good. <span class="text-muted">See for yourself.</span></h2>
                    <p class="lead">Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5 col-md-pull-7">
                    <img class="featurette-image img-responsive center-block" data-src="holder.js/500x500/auto" alt="Generic placeholder image">
                </div>
            </div>

            <hr class="featurette-divider">

            <div class="row featurette">
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <h2 class="featurette-heading">And lastly, this one. <span class="text-muted">Checkmate.</span></h2>
                    <p class="lead">Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <img class="featurette-image img-responsive center-block" data-src="holder.js/500x500/auto" alt="Generic placeholder image">
                </div>
            </div>

            <hr class="featurette-divider">

            <!-- /END THE FEATURETTES -->


            <!-- FOOTER -->
            <footer>
                <p class="pull-right"><a href="#">Back to top</a></p>
                <p>&copy; 2015 Company, Inc. &middot; <a href="#">Privacy</a> &middot; <a href="#">Terms</a></p>
            </footer>

        </div><!-- /.container -->


        <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
        ================================================== -->
        <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->

        <!-- Link to bootstrap.min.js -->
        <script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
        <script src="js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yup, you are correct. I placed my carousel.css incorrectly. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need it if you have used the `data-ride` attribute. I have a feeling that you have not referenced the javascript correctly in your html. Make sure that you do not have any network errors in your browser console and that your resources have been loaded.

Furthermore, you are calling your script before you have loaded jquery and bootstrap.js.

Move your script to initialise your carousel to just before the closing `</body>` tag.

```
    ...
    <script>
      $(function(){
        $('#myCarousel').carousel();
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Bootstraps documentation states that you have to choose one method or the other, so either use javascript to initalise the carousel or the data-ride attribute, but not both.

> The data-ride="carousel" attribute is used to mark a carousel as
>   animating starting at page load. It cannot be used in combination with
>   (redundant and unnecessary) explicit JavaScript initialization of the
>   same carousel.

Comment: You are correct. Turns out that I forgot to change the path for my "carousel.css" to "css/carousel.css"... I took away the little script that manually calls carousel and everything still works fine. Thank you!!